# Play Sound on Application Launch on Win7

Tags: windows-7

How do you make a system sound when launching at application?

Answer (score 0):

They made it very hard in Windows Vista, 7, 8.

You could do something like it:

1. Copy sndrec32.exe from Windows XP or internet to your windows path.
2. Create a .bat file for your application with something with this:

C:\WINDOWS\sndrec32.exe /embedding /min /play /close "C:\WINDOWS\Media\Windows XP Startup.wav"
C:\path\to\your\program.exe